# Can't use the variables in scss

Tags: css, sass

I created a file called `colors.scss`, and later on, I made another file named `header.scss`. However, the variables I used in `header.scss` were originally defined in `colors.scss` could not be implemented.

I have a file named `colors.scss` containing:

```scss
$first: white;
$second: #090c31;
$third: #5853ff;
$dark: rgb(44, 44, 44);
$text1: "Roboto";
$text2: cursive;
```

And then i made another file named `header.scss`:

```scss
@import "colors";

nav {
  width: 100%; 
  padding: 1rem; 
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  position: sticky; 
  background-color: $first;
  top: 0%; 
  z-index: 10;

  > h1 { text-transform: uppercase; }

  > main {
    width: 70%; 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;

    > a {
      color: $dark;
      margin: 1rem;

      &:hover { color: $third; }
    }
  }
}
```

But the variables I used in `header.scss` are not being implemented.

Comment: Is there any error?

Comment: @JahnabiPriyam please share more details like the paths of the two files!

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the path to colors.scss is accurate and does not contain typos or unnecessary characters.
Consider using a relative path:

```
@import "./colors";
```